# int to image to imageview

Tags: android, fonts, widget, clock

I have a custom digital clock widget, where I would like to use a custom font. I have gotten hold of a pice of code that helps me along, but I need help on how to use it. Here is the method:

```
    public static RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context)
{
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Clockopia.ttf");
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setSubpixelText(true);
        paint.setTypeface(clock);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(15);
        myCanvas.drawText("Test", 0, 0, paint);

        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.TimeView, myBitmap);

        return views;
```

}

And here is my updateservice:

```
    private void update() {
    mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    final CharSequence time = DateFormat.format(mTimeFormat, mCalendar);
    final CharSequence date = DateFormat.format(mDateFormat, mCalendar);
    final CharSequence day = DateFormat.format(mDayFormat, mCalendar);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.Day, day);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.Date, date);
    buildUpdate(this);
    ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(this, DigiClock.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    manager.updateAppWidget(widget, views);

}
```

How will I get it to show the time using the buildUpdate method?

Comment: i'm not familiar with widgets so i'm not familiar with the RemoteViews and AppWidgetManager, i'm not sure what that code is responsible for.
i do know the code using to write test using the custom font, but i'm not sure how it will help you, if the font allready looks like a digital clock i guess all you need to do is change the method to look like:buildUpdate(Context context, long seconds) and use myCanvas.drawText(myTime, 0, 0, paint); to paint the new time.